# How to access Active Directory and WMI

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I would like to modernize applications in my job, change Winforms to Blazor Server Side. When I tried to access to PrincipalContext

```
public UserActiveDirectory(string login, string pass) 
{
   _adConnection = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADRESSE_AD, login, pass);
}
```

I have a FileNotFoundException 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement''
I found this article on docs.Microsoft : [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)
The application should be able to display groups, can add user in group, delete,...
I think to have the same problem with WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation).
If anyone has a suggestion, a link to a post.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Try "Install-Package System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time trying to work out how to get the current user's email address - .Net Blazor server app with Windows Authentication. Trying to use Claims was a dead end. As above, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement is the solution. First that package must be installed using NuGet package manager. Then, this Blazor page code may help you:

```
@page "/test"

@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

<h3>App User Data</h3>

<button @onclick="GetData">Get User Data</button>

<p>@authMessage</p>

<p>@surnameMessage</p>
<p>@emailMessage</p>

@code {
    private string authMessage;
    private string surnameMessage;
    private string emailMessage;

    private async Task GetData()
    {
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            authMessage = $"{user.Identity.Name} is authenticated.";
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, user.Identity.Name);

            surnameMessage = principal.Surname;
            emailMessage = principal.EmailAddress;
        }
        else
        {
            authMessage = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
        }
    }
}
```

ALTERNATIVELY, in my service class, I have the following. The #pragma comments stop the warnings that this works only on a Windows server.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement; 
etc
namespace PharmacyCT.Data
{
    public class ExportFileService : IExportFileService
    {
        private readonly string _conn;
        private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _auth;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public ExportFileService(IConfiguration config, AuthenticationStateProvider auth)
    {
        _conn = config.GetConnectionString("PharmCTConn");
        _auth = auth;
        _config = config;
    }
public async Task<string> GetUserEmail()
        {
            var authState = await _auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;
#pragma warning disable CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, user.Identity.Name);
            return principal.EmailAddress;
#pragma warning restore CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks Milney

> Install-Package System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement